# Wagtail add page between two existing pages

Tags: django, content-management-system, graphql, wagtail, graphene-python

I'm using wagtail in a django application with a `graphql` interface. Wagtail is only the backend and I'm implementing an editor with `vuejs` and a `graphql` interface using `graphene`.

I'd like to add a new page between two existing pages. The page order depends on the path parameter of the page. Is it possible to achieve this without manipulating the path param?

I can change the path param of the pages in wagtail, but this seems to me to be error prone and not as the creators of wagtail intended to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagtail uses [Django treebeard](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to enforce the tree structure of pages, and the [Wagtail Page model](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2.2/reference/pages/model_reference.html#methods-and-properties) subclasses the Treebeard `Node` model. I would strongly discourage manipulating the `path` parameters manually, that could completely mess up your structure. Instead use the Treebeard API to add/remove/move pages/nodes around.

The [add_sibling](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.add_sibling) method seems like it'd be the most appropriate here, used like this:

```
new_page = MyPageModel(
    title='My Title'
    slug='foo'
    ...
)
page = Page.objects.get(path='0001...')
page.add_sibling('right', instance=new_page)
```

Your `new_page` will be inserted to the right of your chosen `page`, and all other pages after it will be shifted to the right.